# Enter Strings on 2d array

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I want to input this structure but after typing 3 `-` and pressing Enter I got errors
input:

`---
-m-
p--`

and my code is:
`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    String[][] matrix = new String[n][n];
    for ( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        for ( int j=0 ; j<n ; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = in.nextLine();
        }
    }

    for ( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        for ( int j=0 ; j<n ; j++){
            System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

and error I got is this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>       at Test.main(Test.java:6)

How to fix it and How to enter strings into array

Comment: but first you are taking input of "n". so provide it first.

Comment: @Kaushal28 My mistake but the output is something else.

Comment: input mismatch exception was because "n"

Comment: and what is expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
    int n = in.nextInt();
```

In this line you're entering your string input instead of entering a value to integer n. Firstly, you should enter your integer input to n. (in this case its 3)

Comment: In the question: "I want to input this structure but after typing 3 - and pressing Enter I got errors input:" I think the number 3 before the first dash(-) is meant to be the first input. It is just not formatted properly. So I doubt this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the exception after int n = in.nextInt();, don't you?
Also notice that after that when you call to in.nextLine() for the first time you will have no value.

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
        String[][] matrix = new String[n][n];
        for ( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
            for ( int j=0 ; j<n ; j++){
                matrix[i][j] = in.nextLine();
            }
        }

        for ( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
            for ( int j=0 ; j<n ; j++){
                System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: My mistake; I forgot to enter number 3 at first but when I input it won't stop I have to enter more than 20 elements to print but I expected only 9 elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the use of: `int n = in.nextInt()`. After making this call, you should consume the next line before using the scanner again by calling

```
//consume nextLine()
in.nextLine();
```

The reason you have to do this is because functions like nextInt(), next(), and alike do not consume the '\n' character of your input, so when you press enter after entering your input, the function take everything before that and leaves the '\n' hanging in there. Hope that solves it for you!

Also: nextline() reads by line not by character; if you are entering the inputs like you portray in the question:

```
--- '\n'
-m- '\n'
p-- '\n'
```

the program is not going to work. The program is expecting 9 inputs but you are giving it only three. After making sure you consume the next line after taking in the integer by simply adding this line:

```
//consume nextLine()
in.nextLine();
```

after the line `int n = in.nextInt()`. The program will be expecting the input to be entered in the following way:

3  enter
-  enter
-  enter
-  enter
-  enter
m  enter
-  enter
p  enter
-  enter
-  enter

After that it would start printing. If that is what you want, Good! Otherwise, please tell us more about the problem you are trying to solve